# Looking to represent numbers better on Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi

Is there any way we can restructure the whole numbers in Power BI to distinguish the thousands, millions and billions using normal comma operator.

For example: 1,047,890 is represented as 1047890 or 1.04M in Power BI where as I would like it to be represented as 1,047,890. Is there any way we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Those features are available in the Power BI Desktop tool, a free download from www.powerbi.com.

On the Data view you can set the default numeric format shown in tables, cards, tool-tips etc.  On the Report view you can set the numeric format for Chart Axes etc (those are dynamic by default based on the aggregated results).